# How to store each sql result in a dataframe generated in loops?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I am trying to measure the query processing times of each SQL query. I need to run some SQL queries more than once, but with a randomly generated date range. So i need to save all the results generated in the loop of queries, but in different data frames.

I have tried using globals(), but the problem is i can't generate the shape of the results saved in those lists.

import MySQLdb
import random
from random import randint
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

## import time

## import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

db_connection = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="050194.Piku", db = "lineitem")

cursor = db_connection.cursor()

for x in range(2):
    date_range1 = datetime.date(randint(1992, 1995), randint(1, 12), randint(1, 30))
    date_range2 = datetime.date(randint(1996, 1998), randint(1, 12), randint(1, 30))
    mdate1 = str(date_range1.year) + "-" + str(date_range1.month) + "-" + str(date_range1.day)
    mdate2 = str(date_range2.year) + "-" + str(date_range2.month) + "-" + str(date_range2.day)

```
orderkey = str(randint(1, 6000000))

lineitem_extended_price_range1 = round(random.uniform(900, 90000), 5)
lineitem_extended_price_range2 = round(random.uniform(90001, 110000), 5)
lineitem_ext_price1 = str(lineitem_extended_price_range1)
lineitem_ext_price2 = str(lineitem_extended_price_range2)

order_total_price_range1 = round(random.uniform(850, 85000), 5)
order_total_price_range2 = round(random.uniform(85001, 560000), 5)
order_total_price1 = str(order_total_price_range1)
order_total_price2 = str(order_total_price_range2)



sql_query_lineitem1 = "SELECT * FROM lineitem_table WHERE L_SHIPDATE BETWEEN '" + mdate1 + "' AND '" + mdate2 + "' LIMIT 10;"
# sql_query_lineitem2 = "SELECT * FROM lineitem_table WHERE L_EXTENDEDPRICE BETWEEN '" + lineitem_ext_price1 + "' AND '" + lineitem_ext_price2 + "';"
# sql_query_lineitem3 = "SELECT * FROM lineitem_table WHERE L_ORDERKEY = '" + orderkey + "';"
# sql_query_order4 = "SELECT * FROM order_table WHERE O_ORDERKEY = '" + orderkey + "';"
# sql_query_order5 = "SELECT * FROM order_table WHERE O_ORDERDATE BETWEEN '" + mdate1 + "' AND '" + mdate2 + "';"
# sql_query_order6 = "SELECT * FROM order_table WHERE O_TOTALPRICE BETWEEN '" + order_total_price1 + "' AND '" + order_total_price2 + "';"
# sql_query_join = "SELECT * FROM lineitem_table INNER JOIN order_table ON lineitem_table.L_ORDERKEY = order_table.O_ORDERKEY;"

globals()["mdate1" + str(x)] = mdate1
globals()["mdate2" + str(x)] = mdate2
globals()["ext_price1" + str(x)] = lineitem_ext_price1
globals()["ext_price2" + str(x)] = lineitem_ext_price2
globals()["orderkey" + str(x)] = orderkey
globals()["total_price1" + str(x)] = order_total_price1
globals()["total_price2" + str(x)] = order_total_price2


#average_execution_sum = 0

#initial_time1 = time.time()
cursor.execute(sql_query_lineitem1)
d = pd.DataFrame.from_records(cursor.fetchall(), columns=[desc[0] for desc in cursor.description])




#time_taken1 = time.time() - initial_time

# cursor.execute(sql_query_lineitem2)
# globals()["df_02" + str(x)] = pd.DataFrame.from_records(cursor.fetchall(), columns=[desc[0] for desc in cursor.description])
#
#
# cursor.execute(sql_query_lineitem3)
# globals()["df_03" + str(x)] = pd.DataFrame.from_records(cursor.fetchall(), columns=[desc[0] for desc in cursor.description])
#
#
# cursor.execute(sql_query_order4)
# globals()["df_04" + str(x)] = pd.DataFrame.from_records(cursor.fetchall(), columns=[desc[0] for desc in cursor.description])
#
#
# cursor.execute(sql_query_order5)
# globals()["df_05" + str(x)] = pd.DataFrame.from_records(cursor.fetchall(), columns=[desc[0] for desc in cursor.description])
#
#
# cursor.execute(sql_query_order6)
# globals()["df_06" + str(x)] = pd.DataFrame.from_records(cursor.fetchall(), columns=[desc[0] for desc in cursor.description])
#
#
# cursor.execute(sql_query_join)
# globals()["df_03" + str(x)] = pd.DataFrame.from_records(cursor.fetchall(), columns=[desc[0] for desc in cursor.description])
#
```

cursor.close()
db_connection.close()

print(df_010.shape(0))

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use

```
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name", db_connection)
```

to store the selected table from your SQL query to a pandas data frame df.

Comment: but what if i want to save all the dataframes generated from all the loop of the same query

Comment: You can create an empty list then use `.append(df)` to add the created data frame to it in each step.